# mongodb javascript update

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

How do I update a mongodb collection from JS?

```
db.collection('fruits', function (err, collection) {
    collection.update({ "_id": content.fruitID}, content, function () {
    });
});
```

Am I doing this right? DO I need to use $set?

Basically content is a json object that should replace the document that's found.

Thanks.

I'm using the mongodb node native driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace the document you're doing the right thing. If you want to update a field of the existing document you should use $set.

See here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating